# Is there an R function to extract data from a matrix with associated column and row headings?

Tags: r

I would like to extract all distance variables from a matrix as well the row name and heading for each variable so that I end up with **3 columns** of data: `row1, heading1, 1stdatapoint`

I am able to extract the distance data to a vector but unable to extract the associated row and heading information for each point.

```
Gen.v<-c(Gen.mat)
```

Comment: Please also share what you've tried and doesn't work or perhaps an algorithm you're having hard time implementing. IMO the key is to show that you've made at least some effort to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you want to create a 3-column data frame from the matrix where 1st is the row name, second is the column name and third the value. We can do it using `row` and `col` functions to get row and column indices for each element in matrix and get the corresponding `rownames` and `colnames` respectively.

```
data.frame(row = rownames(Gen.mat)[c(row(Gen.mat))], 
           col = colnames(Gen.mat)[c(col(Gen.mat))], 
           value = c(Gen.mat))

#   row  col value
#1 row1 col1     1
#2 row2 col1    11
#3 row1 col2     2
#4 row2 col2    12
#5 row1 col3     3
#6 row2 col3    13
```

where `Gen.mat` is

```
Gen.mat <- structure(c(1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
c("row1", "row2"), c("col1", "col2", "col3")))

Gen.mat
#     col1 col2 col3
#row1    1    2    3
#row2   11   12   13
```

Comment: Thank you the code worked perfectly. And thanks for the link above, I will include more information next time.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this much easily with `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(Gen.mat)
#.  Var1 Var2 value
#1 row1 col1     1
#2 row2 col1    11
#3 row1 col2     2
#4 row2 col2    12
#5 row1 col3     3
#6 row2 col3    13
```

#### data

```
Gen.mat <- structure(c(1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
 c("row1", "row2"), c("col1", "col2", "col3")))
```